# Docker exec and docker run giving me different resolv.conf hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hostname

I using docker compose to fire up two containers 1. flask webapp 2. mysql database. I have all my scripts written up and Dockerfile all ready to go and working. My app does a ping to other machines by hostnames and requires the `resolv.conf` to be the same as the host computer. After I fire up my docker-compose I can see both my containers running like this :

```
#:~/home/user # docker-compose images
/bin/sh: /tmp/_MEIXmPrg9/libreadline.so.7: no version information available (required by /bin/sh)
/bin/sh: /tmp/_MEIXmPrg9/libreadline.so.7: no version information available (required by /bin/sh)
         Container             Repository     Tag       Image Id      Size
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
webapp-gui_app_1_1b87619cd08b   webapp-gui_app   latest   f0982b82c556   467 MB
webapp-gui_db_1_bd74de835067    mysql          5.7      702fb0b7837f   355 MB
```

On my webapp, the `ping` command is not allowing me to ping by hostname, so when I try to run interactive mode to troubleshoot I noticed that when running with:

```
docker run -it webapp-gui_app_1_1b87619cd08b /bin/sh
```

This gives the correct `resolv.conf` and I am able to successfully ping the hostnames, however, when I run it like this

```
docker exec -u 0 -it webapp-gui_app_1_1b87619cd08b sh
```

My resolv.conf file changes to the following (incorrect `resolv.conf`), and I am not able to ping other local machines by hostname anymore. Does anyone know why?

```
/etc # cat resolv.conf
search mydomain.com
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```